# Impure baseball cap?

Tags: halacha, clothing, animals, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, keilim-purity

I am Chozar Teshuva so if this is a ridiculous question then please bear with me.

Long story short, my cat soiled a ballcap that I own (soil as in, with urine). I put it through the dishwasher, got it nice and clean.  Is it considered ritually impure?  Like would I be able to wear it at all?  Would things I put on my head or touched after touching the hat also be impure?

Comment: Just so you know, DoubleAA's answer below is correct but in any case, there is absolutely no prohibition from becoming ritually impure. In fact, most of us spend most of our lives in that state.

Comment: אין הביישן לומד. Someone embarrassed to ask will never learn. Keep the questions coming!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Excrement and urine of a live animal (and in fact anything except an entire limb from a live animal) are not ritually impure, and thus don't affect your hat. (Rambam Avot HaTumah 2:3)

As an aside, excrement and urine of a deceased animal (as opposed to its flesh) also are not ritually impure. (ibid. 1:15)

Comment: hey thanks for the prompt answer! you are triple AAA in my book..

Comment: Regarding prayer in the presence of something that had animal urine on it but was washed, OP might be reassured by Rambam (*Hil. K'riyas Sh'ma'* [3:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=6&perek=3&halocha=6) and [3:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=6&perek=3&halocha=10); even though the *Shulchan Aruch* OC 79:6 mentions a stringency about animal urine that might possibly extend to cats, this would apply to pure urine rather something that was washed or diluted with the greater of a *r'vi'is* of water per urine deposit or enough to remove the odor).

Comment: Thanks @Fred!  As another aside...main reason I was conerned was for the sake of items I would wear on my head, ie tefillin...

Comment: @user3979986 Glad to help. If the hat was well washed and has no stain or odor, I can't imagine any problem whatsoever. If it was well washed and there was no odor left, but there was some staining left behind, maybe it wouldn't be respectful attire while praying due to the requirement of *hikon* (based on [*Amos* 4:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1504.htm#12); see also *Shabbos* 10a). It is also generally inappropriate to go in public with stained clothes (*Shabbos* 114a). But there would still be no problem with praying or studying Torah in the presence of the hat, or handling the hat.