# Does urine leakage render one ritually impure?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, bathroom

If one leaks a little bit of urine after urinating, does this liquid (in the clothes) render one ritually impure? If not ritually impure, impure in another fashion?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61298/759

Comment: @mil I tried to make your question/title more readable. Please let me know if I missed your original intent.

Answer (score 7):

First step what is the problem of the urine?
**Gemoro** Berachoth 22B

> ת''ר היה עומד בתפלה ומים שותתין על ברכיו פוסק עד שיכלו המים וחוזר ומתפלל להיכן חוזר

But it is **during the micturition**: and in 25A

> "לא אסרה תורה אלא כנגד עמוד בלבד"

"The urine prohibits the Kriath Shema and Tefila during micturition only" But Miderabanan the urine puddle also prohibits. (All this when there is **no fetid odor perceptible in 4 amoth**)

> ומי רגלים כל זמן שמטפיחין מיתיבי מי רגלים כל זמן שמטפיחין אסורין נבלעו או יבשו מותרים

If the urine is **dried or absorbed** enough, and do not wets the hand, it is no longer considered as present.

> הא רשומן ניכר שרי

if it is dried but leaves a **visible** trace, it is permitted.

The odor is an other subject.

But if the urine is not dry and not absorbed quasi totaly, Assur. But we may annul the urine with water.
Note that the **Mishna Brura** in **Shulhan Aruch Orach Chayim** Siman 82 Sayif Koton 4 says that it is permitted indifferently if absorbed in ground or in clothes (but without odor.)

### **In conclusion it is considered as ritually correct.**

Comment: and what if it's covered with other clothes?

Comment: @MrsRGeller   you ass if it is covered upper and lower? in this case May b a din of covered and be allowed but generally the soiled clothe is in direct contact with skin

Comment: but not in direct contact with the HAND